# Rest spring endpoint with transaction maintaining

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I faced up to problem with maintain transaction across multiple request to some endpoint. Let say I've got endpoint payment which handle e.g five request in a row and this five requests should be in one txn scope. Any idea ?

Comment: You cannot... Transactions don't span http requests and never will.

Comment: @M.Deinum: although not the sane thing to do you could save the connection in a session/database and commit/close it on the 5th request

Comment: REST should be stateless, also trying to abuse transactions over HTTP requests isn't something that is easy (although it might sound like that). There is a reason why things like WS-Transaction didn't become popular or widespread.